# procesar datos de php-mysql a json

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo una serie archivos php, ajax y js para poder procesar mi información obtenida desde mi base de datos(MySQL) y al mismo tiempo quiero enviarlos a un modal utilizando un .js

Hasta el momento puedo obtener mi resultado de mi consulta mediante un var_dump:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi consulta, quiero procesarlo a json para posteriormente mandar llamarlo desde un js.

```
 <?php 

$id_sol = $_POST['id'];
$solicitud = SolicitudData::getTraslateAlmacen($id_sol);
echo json_encode($solicitud);
var_dump($solicitud);

?>
```

Este mi .js

```
function obtenerDatos(id){
$.post("index.php?action=getTraslateAlmacen", { id : id }, function( data ){
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#process_id").val(data.id);
    $("#folio").val(data.folio_solicitud);
});
```

}

Investigando lo que me hace  falta es convertir mi consultar de php a objetos json pero no logro obtenerlo.

Comment: Ya lo tienes hecho aquí:  `echo json_encode($solicitud);`, lo que pasa es que el `var_dump` que tienes a continuación te fastidia todo, porque la petición `post` lo que está recibiendo es lo que imprime el `var_dump`, si lo quitas debería funcionar. En ocasiones no es necesario usar `JSON.parse`. Si te da problemas, puedes comentar también esa línea y probar.

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado de hacer `console.log(data);` y comentar las líneas `\\var data = JSON.parse(data); \\$("#process_id").val(data.id); \\$("#folio").val(data.folio_solicitud);`?

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Marcos, @A. Cedano, aparentemente estoy bien pero ya intente sus opciones y no me muestra, el var_dump solo lo tengo de referencia, el `console.log(data);` no muestra nada de error en la consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre una solución, gracias por sus aportes, lo comparto por si alguien más tiene algo similar:

```
    <?php

$id_sol = $_POST['id'];

$solicitud = SolicitudData::getTraslateAlmacen($id_sol); 

foreach ($solicitud as $key) {

    $response[0] = [
                    "id"=>$key->id,
                    "folio"=>$key->folio,
                    "pedimento"=>$key->ped,
                    "nombre_solicitante"=>utf8_decode($key->nombre),
                    "cliente_id"=>$key->cliente_id
                    ];

    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo no funciona por el var_dump, para que no hagas ningun parse en el javascript debes enviar los headers correctos el codigo seria asi:

```
<?php 
    $id_sol = $_POST['id'];
    $solicitud = SolicitudData::getTraslateAlmacen($id_sol);
    header("content-type: application/json");    
    echo json_encode($solicitud);
```

Y en el javascript quedaria asi

```
function obtenerDatos(id){
$.post("index.php?action=getTraslateAlmacen", { id : id }, function( data ){
    if(typeof data !='object'){
       alert('hubo un error en la respuesta del servidor');
       return;
    }
    $("#process_id").val(data.id);
    $("#folio").val(data.folio_solicitud);
});
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato @aquiles ya intente tu sugerencia y me sigue sin mostrar los datos de mi consulta., y tampoco me muestra ningun error en la consola

Comment: y si le haces un var_dump a $solicitud trae resultados?